# Array Only Prints Certain Elements and Not Others

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I am currently in a Intro to Computer Language class and everyone few lessons I have to develop some minimal programs (we are given 5 different prompts and have to pick three of them to complete). Due to time, I moved on and completed a different program, but I still want to understand what is going wrong with this one. 
It is supposed to translate a given phrase into Pig Latin using for loops and different methods (as broken down in their template, which I cannot change, though I know there is a more efficient way). I can get the words in the phrases to translate, but when I print out the array (either by converting it to a string or running a for loop to print each element out separately) some of the elements only print the reference code. Could someone tell me what's going on? Below is the code and then a sample of a few print outs.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PigLatin {
  public static void main (String[] args){
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String userWord;

      userWord = scnr.nextLine();
      userWord = userWord.toLowerCase();

      String[] wordArry = userWord.split(" ");

      print(wordArry);
  }

  public static String[] translate(String[] words){
     String[] pigLatin = new String[words.length];

     for (int i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
         if (isVowel(words[i].charAt(0)) == true){
             pigLatin[i] = words + "ay"; 
         }
         else if (words[i].charAt(0) == 'y') {
             pigLatin[i] = words[i].substring(findFirstVowel(words[i]), words[i].length()) + words[i].substring(0, findFirstVowel(words[i])) + "ay";
         }
         else {
             pigLatin[i] = words[i].substring(findFirstVowel(words[i]), words[i].length()) + words[i].substring(0, findFirstVowel(words[i])) + "ay";
         }
     }
     return pigLatin;
  }
  public static int findFirstVowel(String s){
      char[] vowList = {'a','e','i','o','u','y'};

        for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < vowList.length; ++j) {
                if (s.charAt(i) == vowList[j]) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
    return -1;
   }
  public static boolean isVowel(char c){
      boolean vowel = false;
      char[] vowList = {'a','e','i','o','u'};

      for (int i = 0; i < vowList.length; ++i) {
          if (c == vowList[i]) {
              vowel = true;
          }
      }
      return vowel;
  }
  public static void print(String[] words){

      String[] newArry = new String[words.length];

      for (int i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
          newArry[i] = words[i];
      }

      String finalPrint = Arrays.toString(translate(newArry));
      finalPrint = finalPrint.replace("[", "");
      finalPrint = finalPrint.replace(",", "");
      finalPrint = finalPrint.replace("]", "");

      System.out.println(finalPrint);

  }
}
```

Here are some of the printed responses:

Input: the rain in spain stays mainly in the plain
Output: ethay ainray [Ljava.lang.String;@17c68925ay ainspay aysstay ainlymay [Ljava.lang.String;@17c68925ay ethay ainplay 
Expected: ethay ainray inay ainspay aysstay ainlymay inay ethay ainplay

Input: you should have stayed with the soup question
OutPut: ouyay ouldshay avehay ayedstay ithway ethay oupsay uestionqay
This print's out correctly

Input: the stuff that dreams are made of
Output: ethay uffstay atthay eamsdray [Ljava.lang.String;@17c68925ay ademay [Ljava.lang.String;@17c68925ay 
Expected: ethay uffstay atthay eamsdray areay ademay ofay

I cannot find an answer as to why this is happening. Please let me know if you need any additional information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pigLatin[i] = words + "ay";
```

This line. You are appending string to an array. Change it to:

```
pigLatin[i] = words[i] + "ay";
```

---

Side note 1:

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
    newArry[i] = words[i];
}
```

This loop can be changed to:

```
System.arraycopy(words, 0, newArry, 0, words.length);
```

---

Side note 2:

Splitting on `"\\s+"` is better. It also takes care of multiple spaces.

---

Side note 3:

```
if (isVowel(words[i].charAt(0)) == true) {
```

This can be simplified as:

```
if (isVowel(words[i].charAt(0))) {
```

---

Side note 4:

```
for (char value : vowList) {
    if (c == value) {
        vowel = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Using break for slightly better performance. Also, using foreach loop.

---

Final side note:

```
finalPrint = finalPrint.replace("[", "")
        .replace(",", "")
        .replace("]", "");
```

Chaining of replace calls.

Comment: I made that change and you are absolutely right! That did fix it! I'm still new and we just started working with arrays. Now I just need to figure out why my isVowel method needs to recognize 'y' as a vowel when the program is supposed to treat it like a consonant if it is the first character (that's why there is the if statement even though it is technically address in the isVowel method), lol. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds good. You may look at my side notes as well for better coding.

Comment: Thanks for those! Any little bit helps. I do still have one question, though. Why did the original code work for some works and not the others? Your fix corrected the issue, but I still don't understand why it only worked some of the time.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake (typo, likely) in this block:

```
if (isVowel(words[i].charAt(0)) == true){
    pigLatin[i] = words + "ay"; 
}
```

It should be instead (note you don't need to compare boolean value with `true`):

```
if (isVowel(words[i].charAt(0))) {
    pigLatin[i] = words[i] + "ay";
}
```

Also, you don't need to copy your array in print() method - translate() doesn't modify input array in any way.

Finally, instead of replacing the output of Arrays.toString, you could use String.join, so your print method would look like:

```
public static void print(String[] words){
    System.out.println(String.join(" ", translate(words)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly the problem. I'm still new to arrays and I couldn't wrap my head around that one.